# Disallow google robot from robots.txt and list sitemap instead

Tags: html, sitemap, robots.txt

I am using a paid geolocation script to direct users to specific sites based on country.
However, I am getting charged a lot because robots keep crawling every page of my large site.

If I were to disallow google within the robots.txt and provide a sitemap within the robots.txt would google still index my page without crawling?

Example

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Sitemap: sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google index only with crawling...

The best thing to do for you, is to disable the geolocation script when you detect a Google robot (or other)
You can recognize them in various ways: HTTP_USER_AGENT or HTTP_FROM, or IP